# Does the application server TomEE support EJB 2?

Tags: tomcat

### The Situation

We have legacy JavaEE software which still uses EJB 2. We want to upgrade to a modern application server for security reasons.

### The Question

Currently at the top of our short list of application server candidates is TomEE. **Does TomEE support EJB 2?**

### Rationale

When we upgraded, we first tried a different server and started getting errors, including errors about features no longer supported. One such feature no longer supported was EJB 2 entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache TomEE AS use Apache OpenEJB as Enterprise JavaBeans implementation.
According the [OpenEJB documentation](http://openejb.apache.org/faq.html), the answer to your question is **YES TomEE support the EJB 2 specification**. Personally, I've never try this.

You can also have a look [to this given example](http://tomee.apache.org/ejb-2.1-compatibility-example.html) of using EJB 2 with TomEE.

Good luck, TomEE is a very good choice.